# How is Ruby Mechanize fast after first get request?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I recently programmed a scraper with Ruby's Mechanize gem for the first time. It had to hit the server (some 'xyz.com/a/*number*') where the number will be generated by the script. Like 'xyz.com/a/2' and 'xyz.com/a/3'. 
It turned out that the first request took a lot of time -- around 1.5s on a 512kbps connection. But the next request was done in 0.3ms.

How could it be done so fast? Did it have some caching mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of possible sources for a speed change between requests. A few that immediately spring to mind:

- DNS lookup cached on your client. The first call must convert "xyz.com" to "123.45.67.89", involving a DNS lookup which may be slow.
- HTTP keep-alive. There is an initial conversation between client and server to start an HTTP data transfer. On a high-latency connection you will notice this. If server and client both respect HTTP keep-alive, then a connection can be established once to cover multiple requests.
- Server-side caching. The server you are scraping uses caching to speed up multiple similar requests. It might be caching data to do with your current session for example, or even just not fully compiled the script yet until your first request.
- Server-side VM resource allocation. If the server is sharing space on a virtualised system, and does not serve high traffic, then it may become more responsive after the first request ensures everything is in RAM and has CPU allocated.

This is by no means exhaustive. The above examples are just to illustrate that this behaviour - initial slow response, followed by faster ones - is  very common for web services, and has multiple causes.